# How to debug a Firebase Auth Blocking function

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

I would like to locally run Firebase Auth Blocking functions to test a code that I want to run for `beforeUserCreated`. One of the sources that I am looking on how to achieve that is this: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/Node/quickstarts/auth-blocking-functions

But it won't help me understand what I need to do in order to run the emulator and test the function itself. In that sample, it will block if the user domain is not "@acme.com".

So I am pretty much trying to find docs that will help me understand what I need to to with firebase emulators and how to test my function, locally, for the beforeUserCreated Auth Blocking Function. Could someone point me directions?

UPDATE

I also got info that for blocking function I need to add these lines to firebase.json

```
 "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099,
      "preauth":{  //new stuff 
        "disable_warnings": true,
        "metadata": {
          "providers": [
            {
              "uid": "custom",
              "displayName": "Custom Auth Emulator",
              "createRequestProcessor": "./functions/beforeUserCreated.js"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
```

That `beforeUserCreated.js` content right now is just this:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

exports.beforeUserCreated = async (user) => {
  if (!user.emails.endsWith("@example.com")) {
    console.error("ERRROR");
  }
  console.error("NOT IN THE ERROR");

  return null;
};

module.exports = exports;
```

Now, if I make a call using http://localhost:9099/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=myKey and passing as payload an email and password, I am getting an error from the console related to a function I have for validating the user, not the same as the one above from the firebase.json, but it is progress.. By the way, the error is related missing the project credentials. I will try to look that up and will post if I find a solution.

Comment: To learn about the emulators, have a look at: https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite. Outside of that, you shouldn't need much more than to run the Cloud Functions and Auth emulators, and then run the function there. If you try that, what happens? Any error message?

Comment: I did manage to have the functions startup by joining some of the information of that page along with other pieces I got from the internet and fixing an import on the code. But I am unable to trigger the `beforeUserCreated`. It does not trigger if I try to create a user through the authentication emulator, and it does not work either if I call the create endpoint `http://localhost:9099/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=myKey`